# How to get sum of parent column group the bottom of a table?

Tags: reporting-services

I've a dataset on orders, their category, month of order, status and amount.

```
+----------+---------------+-------+--------+--------+
|  name    |  category     | month | amount | status |
+----------+---------------+-------+--------+--------+
|  order 1 |  electronics  | April |   100  |  Paid  |
|  order 2 |  electronics  | May   |    50  |  Paid  |
|  order 3 |  electronics  | April |    20  |  Credit|
|  order 4 |  stationary   | May   |    10  |  Paid  |
|  order 5 |  stationary   | April |   150  |  Credit|
|  order 6 |  miscellaneous| May   |    40  |  Paid  |
|  order 7 |  miscellaneous| May   |    10  |  Paid  |
|  order 8 |  Grocery      | April |   100  |  Credit|
|  order 9 |  Grocery      | April |    10  |  Credit|
|  order 10|  Grocery      | May   |    20  |  Paid  |
+----------+---------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

My report table needs to look like this:

```
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|                |     April     |      May       |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|  Category      |  Paid | Credit|  Paid| Credit  |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|  electronics   |  100  |   20  |   50  |   0    |
|  stationary    |  0    |   150 |   10  |   0    |
|  miscellaneous |  0    |   0   |   50  |   0    |
|  grocery       |  0    |   110 |   20  |   0    |
|  Grand Total   |  100  |   280 |   130 |   0    |
|  Monthly total |      380      |       0        |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Except for monthly total, I've got it working.

Row group - group by category.

Column groups - month as parent group and status as it child.

I tried adding a new row below the **"Grand Total"** with and expression `=Sum(Fields!amount.Value,"month parent group")` but it sums up values below both Paid and Credit columns. I need it to be merged instead.

I was able to get the merged result just below Month names in a row too, by just summing the amounts.

But not able to do the same the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you are looking for??

[image]

If yes then as below, go to [Sum(amount)] and there add total as Column, if you add it as row it will give you same as Grand Total.

Now you can hide total for each row and keep only complete total.

Note: You wont be get 380 as Total below your Month as you have 2 column grouping been used.

[image]

Comment: If there  a better way to display in the format my client wanted, without using the column groupings?

Comment: I am not sure about that, not top of my mind, may be someone experience could add some more idea but for now this is your good to go solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution with Python, [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). You can use this code to create your table:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"category": ["electronics", "electronics", "electronics", 
                            "stationary", "stationary","miscellaneous", "miscellaneous", 
                            "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery"],
                "month": ["April", "May", "April", 
                            "May", "April","May", "May", 
                            "April", "April", "May"],
                "amount": [100, 50, 20, 10, 150, 40, 10, 100, 10, 20],
                "status": ["Paid", "Paid", "Credit", "Paid", "Credit",
                              "Paid", "Paid", "Credit", "Credit", "Paid"]})
```

than use pivot table

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=["month","status"],values=["amount"],
           columns=["category"],aggfunc=[np.sum], fill_value=0, margins = True)
```

this will give you table with Grand Total margins. For the Monthly Totals add these to your code

```
pd.concat([
d.append(d.sum().rename((k, 'Total')))
for k, d in table.groupby(level=0)
]).append(table.sum().rename(('Grand', 'Total')))
```

You have what you need.